# Infinite Loop in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

While executing insert query, i got endless infinite loop (i think so). It never comes to an end.
Below is my query

```
ALTER proc [dbo].[InsertNomineeImage] 
@UserId int,
@ContestId int,
@ImagePath varchar(150),
@Name varchar(50),
@Description varchar(500)

As
BEGIN
    Begin TRY
        BEGIN TRAN

        Declare @Id as int

        insert into UserImages(UserId,ImagePath,Name,Description,IsActive) 
        values(@UserId,@ImagePath,@Name,@Description,'False')

        set @Id=SCOPE_IDENTITY();


        Insert into UserContestImages(UserId,ContestId,UserImage,ParticipationDate,IsActive) 
        values (@UserId,@ContestId,@Id,GETDATE(),'False')

        COMMIT TRAN

    END TRY
    BEGIN CATCH
        IF @@ERROR > 0
            ROLLBACK TRAN

    END CATCH


End
```

Comment: Where would the loop be?  All I see are two simple insert statements.

Comment: What is it that actually happens? You execute this SP and it never returns?

Comment: @dan1111 `SCOPE_IDENTITY` is a system function

Comment: Scope_Identity() is built in function

Comment: @IvanG : It goes into endless run....

Comment: @IvanG, sorry my mistake.  I just discovered that.

Comment: What is the datatype of `IsActive` field in `UserImages` and `UserContestImages` tables?

Comment: This is a long shot, but you can try it, maybe your connection has some uncommitted transactions created while you were developing this procedure, mark `ROLLBACK` with mouse within window in SSMS in which you were creating this code and execute it (so that only `ROLLBACK` gets executed).

Comment: This is not a loop issue is a loock issue.

Comment: @IvanG - Thanks you were right. Actually the developer had an uncommitted transaction on the database from the code behind. And we were trying at Sql Management Studio... Thanks a ton

Comment: @AmitRanjan You're welcome, same thing happened to me on quite a few occasions when I was experimenting with transactions. All the queries (including other users) on the databases slowed down when this happened...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Odds are high that this is a blocking issue, not a loop.

While this is running, open SSMS and run SP_WHO2 ACTIVE. It will show you all spids that are doing something - yours will be in there. There is a column 'BlkBy' - if there is a number in that column, then the query is blocked (waiting for another process to complete and release its lock), and that is the number of the session that is blocking your query. Investigate what that session is doing and you will have your answer.